# how to deny view to all pages and allow only for certain on wiki

Tags: permalinks, wiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I'm using MediaWiki 1.27.4  running on Ubuntu 16.4 I've got confused with the following task: how to deny view to All pages for certain users (who has account in my wiki) or How to allow view per group . The goal to achieve is to have no access to pages on wiki except allowed few for some users.

I've tried some extensions but can't find a solution for ~180 pages and less than hundred of users.

Comment: Generally it's best not to. See the warning in the access control docs: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_viewing_of_certain_specific_pages

Comment: just for business need and  learn how

Comment: Have you looked at [Manual:User rights](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights)? You just need to deny them the `read` right.

Comment: Yes add it to Conf file